# elasticsearch return list of index that matches the search

Tags: elasticsearch

My _index name is something like "house_2019_01_01", basically house_yyyy_MM_dd. _type can be something like "condo", "singlefamily" and "townhome". I just want to return a list of indexes that match house_2019* and _type = "condo". How should I search it?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "_index": "house_2019"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "_type": "condo"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "indexes": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index"
      }
    }
  }
}
```